# What was the lore behind Genshin Fabulous Fungus Frenzy secret events?

Tags: genshin-impact

Unknowingly to most players the recent Fabulous Fungus Frenzy limited time story featured some secret events that were not listed in the quest log.

While playing thru the event quests it was possible during very specific time frames to find some npc at a secret location on the opposite side of the map, north of Chatrakam cave:

1. Sido investigating (soon after the second quest in the chain, right at the start of the third one)
2. Elchingen talking to himself,  referencing a "master" in the process (after third quest)
3. An assassin probably dispatched to eliminate Elchingen. This was not timegated and could be experienced anytime after completing the main story.

All three can be seen in this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LNcKfdo9yQ).

The event foreshadows Cyno investigation and Elchingen real plan from the start, and Miko only reinforces that - multiple times. But while the player is made aware that something weird is happening, I could not find any clue that would direct someone to check the specific location near of Chatrakam. You see Cyno and Sido during the event, and at the end Yae mentions that Elchingen  may try to escape but by now it would be too late to see the first two secrets and anyway she does not give any clue about Chatrakam, so while Paimon DOES indeed say a line that could be seen as 4th wall hanging soon afterward, saying that she "should take notice of everything Yae says in the future" this will easily go unnoticed...

So, the question is simple: **did the event really resorted in players randomly visiting the secret location during those tight time windows or I am missing some lore reasons that would point the player to Chatrakam**?
To put this into perspective: almost no video about the "secret ending" of the event actually mentions the first two secrets, and Sido even says that "you must have nothing to do if you came there now" when you find him...

Comment: I found Chile and Yoimiya hunting Yokai, and she was helping him buy gifts for his siblings before heading back to Snezhnaya